# Is fire more harmful than a phone?

Tags: energy, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, microwaves

I have read somewhere that the higher the frequency of electromagnetic radiation, the higher the damage it causes to your body, and visible light has a very high frequency in comparison to microwave rays, released by phones.

So, does this mean that fire is, comparatively, more harmful than phone?
Visible light has a frequency from about **400-700 THz** and microwaves have a frequency from about **300 GHz to 300 MHz.**

Also, does this mean that the higher the energy, the higher the damage (as frequency is directly proportional to total energy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simplify the effects of EM radiation on biological systems to simply $E=hf$ because  different materials absorb or transmit different frequencies preferentially. $E=hf$ tells us the energy per photon, but it doesn't tell us how much is absorbed by any particular type of cell. It also doesn't tell us the intensity of the radiation (energy per second per area).

Regarding absorption preferences, x-rays are absorbed by bone but not so much by vascular tissue.  Different frequencies (wavelengths) of x-rays are absorbed in different amounts.  Lower frequency radio waves and microwaves (MHz to GHz range) are absorbed by water-bearing tissues, but the energy/photon is much less than an x-ray photon.

Visible light is mostly harmless to skin, but slightly higher energy UV radiation will damage skin DNA due to a resonance absorption in the DNA.

Gamma rays (E/photon ~> 100 keV ) definitely have a greater potential to damage cells *if* they are absorbed, but again if the intensity is low, there is generally negligible damage to the system.

So, high intensity microwave/radar could possibly be more dangerous than low intensity gamma, depending on the tissue involved.  It's a very complex problem that requires good experimental research.

Bottom line:  absorption coefficients/resonances and source intensity are more important than energy/photon.

Comment: What are the basses of the experimentation that prove it? (just for my knowledge)

Comment: What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't mentioned it.

Comment: It means that - high intensity microwave/radar is more dangerous than low intensity gamma rays.

Comment: I said "could possibly."  Imagine the following situation. There is a 5 microrcurie Cs-137 source in a room. You are seated 3 m away from it. There is also a 1000 W microwave antenna radiating in the room. Your eyes are 1/2 m away from it.   Which one would you be more concerned about?

Comment: Cs-137 are radioactive isotope, I will more concerned about it.

Comment: Then you don't understand the idea of intensity.  The radioactive source is so weak and so far away that it is depositing very little power in you.  The microwave is going to fry your eyes long before there is anything to worry about from the Cs.  Just because something is radioactive doesn't mean you should automatically fear it. Radioactive simply means that it spontaneously emits energy due to a reduction of mass.

Comment: The power of the Cs-137 source is about 20 nW.  If your body has an exposure cross section of 1 $m^2$ (that's big), at three meters from the source you are receiving 0.88% at your surface (0.18 nW), and then much of that travels right through your body without interacting.  0.18 nW versus 1000 W, and water-bearing tissues (e.g., eyes) absorb microwave more efficiently than they absorb gammas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38691/discussion-between-vaibhavtech-and-bill-n).